# ubuntu 14.04.2 - what nvidia drivers for CUDA

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, xorg, cuda

after installing cuda toolkit and cuda samples via runfile installation (nvidia driver installed separately - NVIDIA binary driver - version 340.76 from nvidia-340 (open source)))

after running ./deviceQuery i have this:

```
./deviceQuery Starting...

CUDA Device Query (Runtime API) version (CUDART static linking)

cudaGetDeviceCount returned 30
-> unknown error
Result = FAIL
```

nvidia-smi gives me this:

```
+------------------------------------------------------+                       
| NVIDIA-SMI 340.76     Driver Version: 340.76         |                       
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 780 Ti  Off  | 0000:01:00.0     N/A |                  N/A |
| 37%   35C    P8    N/A /  N/A |    287MiB /  3071MiB |     N/A      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

So the question is which nvidia driver will satisfy CUDA set?

As far as I know there is no xordg/edgers nvidia drivers for ubuntu 14.04.2 ?

?

Answer (score 1):

I use Nvidia drivers from `nvidia-331` package from official Ubuntu repository on Ubuntu 14.04.2.

Recently something changed in drivers packages and CUDA stopped working, the symptom was error 30 ("Unknown error") in first CUDA-related operation.

After some debugging I investigated that problem was with missing nvidia_uvm kernel module.
Check that it is loaded:

```
$ lsmod | grep nvidia
nvidia_uvm             34855  0 
nvidia              10744943  84 nvidia_uvm
drm                   303102  2 nvidia
```

If it's not loaded, check that you have installed appropriate package, for 331 version it is `nvidia-331-uvm`:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331-uvm
```

But this is not enough: nvidia_uvm can't be loaded in straightforward way (e.g. by running `modprobe nvidia_uvm`), you need to either run you program as root (once, then module will be loaded and root permissions will no longer be required), or (recommended) install `nvidia-modprobe` package and reboot:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-modprobe
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21751/discussion-on-answer-by-rutsky-ubuntu-14-04-2-what-nvidia-drivers-for-cuda).

Answer (score 0):

After much reading up, I got CUDA 6.5 working on Ubuntu 14.04 with an NVIDIA GeForce GT525M graphics processor and an integrated Intel graphics card.

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to open the terminal.

```
sudo service lightdm stop
sudo killall Xorg
```

Now install the graphics driver. I had to use the nvidia 340.29 driver that comes along with the CUDA run file. If you have an integrated Intel graphics card, you must use the `--no-opengl-files` option.

```
sudo ./NVIDIA-Linux-x86_64-340.29.run --no-opengl-files
```

At the end of the installation, do NOT let Nvidia reconfigure Xorg config files.

After that, load the Nvidia module:

```
sudo modprobe nvidia
```

and then you can install the CUDA Toolkit and samples:

```
sudo ./cuda-linux64-rel-6.5.14-18749181.run
sudo ./cuda-samples-linux-6.5.14-18745345.run
```

Reboot and verify from the "Additional Drivers" section in Systems Settings -> Software & Updates that "Manually installed driver" is selected. Now you can build and test `deviceQuery` and it should work without error.

The [Nvidia CUDA Getting Started Guide for Linux](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/6_5/rel/docs/CUDA_Getting_Started_Linux.pdf) talks about all these in detail.